# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 along windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have formatted a 55gb partition hard drive for UBUNTU. How do I install it on that partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204653/i-have-formatted-a-55gb-partition-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-how-do-i-install-it-on)

I want to Installing Ubuntu 12.04 along windows 7 and I have 500 GB Hard Disk and I have already partitioned it to 100 GB As C, 100 GB As D: Drive, 100 GB As E Drive and Remaining As F: Drive. So What would be the best course of action to install Ubuntu in D: Drive?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? if you have plenty, you can use virtualbox to run ubuntu on seven.

Comment: @EvandroSilva I have 2gb RAM

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204653/i-have-formatted-a-55gb-partition-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-how-do-i-install-it-on

Answer (score 1):

If you want dual system just boot from ubuntu live cd and chose `try without installing.` So you will easy acces to full desktop environment available.
Then press to install ubuntu and follow this instructions

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ

Best choise is to make / ex4 primary partition with 20 gigs of amount space(as it says in official instruction 15 is  enough) Then make swap partition with double amount size of your ram and finaly create /home ex4 partition there will be  all files stored so make it big enough to have media and downloads.Then if you continue to install without mesing up windows drive system grub will detect your windows partition and put it in boot list

Comment: I am new for ubuntu so could u please explain me more detially

Comment: ok but first try to watch video i putted in comment. Windows drive issue presented in video.Then ask whatever you want.This guy make good tutorials and have partnership with youtube.

Comment: does I need to delete my partition of D: Drive to install Ubuntu 12.04 and re partition it to root, home & swap?

Comment: @polartenuchie I have to do this with Gpart or the disk management tool of windows itself?

Comment: i reccomend using gparted to make free space, then create  3 partitions using free space 1) ex4 set it to be '/' for 20-30 gigs amount of space,2) /home with big amount of space you like -ex4 type, then 3)create linuxswap http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/