# Install Ubuntu 12.04 on Drive "D"?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Dell Inspiron 531S that originally came loaded with Windows Vista.  A couple years ago I purchased a copy of Windows 7, formatted the hard drive and installed the updated operating system.  In the process I formatted the 10 GB recovery drive partition on drive D as it was no longer needed for Windows Vista.  I would really like to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 using the empty 10 GB drive D:.  I have two questions.

(1)  Can Ubuntu be installed on a separate partition, a drive removed from the boot sector on drive C:?

(2)  If so would Grub be installed in the boot sector and properly select Windows 7 on drive C: or Ubuntu 12.04 on drive D?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/204653/i-have-formatted-a-55gb-partition-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-how-do-i-install-it-on

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the ubuntu installer will handle both questions automatically. You only will have to select the partition to install ubuntu. One thing: Drive D, will probably be `sda2` in ubuntu but you will be able to see which partition is what by the different sizes.

Regarding question1, installing on a separate partition is the only good way to install it in my opinion. Anyways, this is the default way, if you have only 1 partition with windows, the installer will split it and install ubuntu on the 2nd one.