# Installing Ubuntu, dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu, having looked at it on CD, without any success.
First attempt at install didn't give me any options where to install it, and it wiped out one of my Windows XP disks and had to reformat (despite choosing install alongside Windows).
Second attempt, using manual install, offered me about 30 choices involving all sorts of raid set-ups that I couldn't understand, and I could not figure out where the disk I have ready for Ubuntu was actually listed.
Third attempt involved wupi, which put it where I want it, but under Windows. I do NOT get a choice of operating system at boot - it just goes into Windows, so I can't access it. The Boot.ini file has clearly not been altered correctly.
All I want to do is install it onto my disk H, which is cleared and ready for use just by Ubuntu, and have a dual boot system, without Ubuntu dependent on Windows. Preferably with boot menu choice on boot up, but I can manually select disk H to boot from if need be. I do NOT need or want to partition the physical disk - it can all go to Ubuntu.
This should be simple - but I haven't yet found any directions as to how to achieve it.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/204653/i-have-formatted-a-55gb-partition-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-how-do-i-install-it-on/204665#204665

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to install Ubuntu on your system independently of windows and it to be on H drive. There is a simple way to do it.

1. Right click on "My Computer"
2. Go to Manage
3. click on Disk management
4. There you will find H: drive
5. Right click on it and Delete that volume

Now that is a free partition, and you can use it for your Ubuntu installation. All you have to do is while installing Ubuntu whenever you get an option to select drive for installation select "**USE FREE SPACE**". It will automatically get installed on H: which we made as free partition.