# Dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: 12.10

I looked at the questions regarding dual-booting with Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 and couldn't locate an answer.  Can I simply install Ubuntu to a free partition and it will automatically ask me each time I reboot which OS I would like to use?

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Ubuntu 18.04 and above**

New installations of recent versions of Ubuntu does not use a separate swap partition any more. They use a swap file by default.

**Original Answer**

Ubuntu by default uses two partitions, one of type `ext4` and the other of type `Swap`. Windows uses NTFS partitions not useful for Ubuntu installation.

If you have a free partition in Windows, delete it using Windows Disk Management Tool. Keep the free space **unallocated**.

When you install Ubuntu, choose the **Install side by side Windows** option. Ubuntu will find the unallocated space and create the partitions it needs.

See [Ubuntu installation on Windows7 with D partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition) for more details.

The default installation of Ubuntu includes a boot-loader called GRUB. **Every time you boot GRUB will load before Windows or Ubuntu and give you the choice to boot either Ubuntu or Windows**. If you do not choose anything, it will boot Ubuntu after waiting for a while. Both the time it waits and the default boot can be changed later.

Hope this helps

Comment: OP - In other words, yes. If you install it on a different partition than your Windows install, it will ask you each time you reboot which OS you want to use. :)