# installing ubuntu in a predefined partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, boot-partition

my 500 gb hdd has 5 partition. 4 among of them are of NTFS file system and partially occupied with data. another partition where i want to install ubuntu is of 52 gb. now i want to know in which file system i have to format that particular partition to install ubuntu. Please provide the link or step by step procedure of such type installing keeping in mind that i can not resize/move/shrink my NTFS partion at present as i have to recover some deleted files from that partition - however i will do the same later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete the ntfs, create a swap partition the same size as your system memory, the remaining space should be formatted as ext4, the ubuntu installer has a "custom" option which can be used for this

Comment: Ubuntu needs at least two partitions, swap, and `/` to work smoothly. See this answer for detailed explanations: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition/204699#204699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot up with live Ubuntu CD or [bootable](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) Ubuntu usb
2. Choose 'Something else' installation type
3. Delete the partition in which to install Ubuntu
4. Create Ext4 partition and separate swap space greater than equal to your physical RAM
5. Select the mount point for Ext4 partition to be '/'
6. Perform install.

Note: Creating a separate partition for home folder is a good idea. You can refer to [this](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installseparatehome) article for that.

Also, You can refer to [this](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/) article for step-by-step installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: thank all of you ..i have successfully install ubuntu 12.10.  but i'm facing a problem for internet connection. my huwai e303c usb modem is not working with ubuntu. i already have installed the driver given with the device. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure to solve your  internet problem, You can post another question regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

The partition can be some like this. If you wanna reinstall, you can format root partition only and your home partition still safe.

[image]