# Configuring partitions during install

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'd like to install Ubuntu on my computer. I have a 500GB HDD with the following partitions: (at least what the Ubuntu installer shows):

```
/
- Windows 7 (loader)
- 100GB 
- 400GB
```

I'd like to install Ubuntu to the 100GB partition as on the 400GB I have Windows. But I have problems with the following:

1. Whether I can set a swap particion without messing up my Windows.
2. Which file system to set to the partition.

Please tell me what and how to do it in the installer.

Comment: See [Ubuntu installation on Windows7 with D:\ partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition)

Answer (score 1):

In the 100GB free space you could set up a partition as big as your memory, ie.: 4GB for swapping. then you may use the rest 97 GB for ubuntu.
You may create those partitions as primary, as IDE/SATA allows 4 primary partitions to exist.
At installation time, do set the ubuntu partition as bootable.

When asked, you may install the ubuntu boot loader to the MBR, and let GRUB manage the booting partitions. Other wise, you should configure the boot manager of W7 to learn about the new ubuntu's booting partition and this way be able to start ubuntu.
On the other hand, GRUB will let  you start the OS you may like.

All that may be done at the installation process of ubuntu, when hard drive partitioning.

My advice: when in the ubuntu's disk partitioning section of the installation process, create a partition for the root - / - file system about 30GB big (this one si the one to be set up as bootable), a 4GB partition for the swap and a 66GB partition for /home, that is users directories. Use Ext4 file systems, as it is stable, tested and well known to work. Do use GRUB.

Farewell.

Comment: When I open the particion manager it warns me that **It would erase all the contect from the particions, and thats can't be undone.**

Now what to do? I can't risk to lose my windows.

Comment: @gen If you can't risk losing your Windows then you shouldn't do this. The chance of actually losing it is low, but one wrong move by you could completely kill it.