# Can I install Ubuntu on a separate HDD to my Windows installation?

Tags: windows, drive

My Windows installation is on C drive, and I want to install a new Ubuntu installation on D drive. I have some downloads on my D drive like anime and stuff (nothing directly relating to the windows installation).

Is it possible?  I've been googling everywhere but the forums are down and I'm a complete newbie. Keep in mind I would rather not format my D drive but if it comes down to it I can. Both drives have 300GiB free space. Even if you forward me onto another site any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: it's also known as dual-boot, it's not limited to one HDD.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu on a separate disk you will need to format that disk. But you can partition the disk before, so you can install it on one partition of your D drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu in free space of D drive, just resize the partition of D drive and make some space available for D drive.

Insert the Ubuntu OS Cd and custom the partitions, leave NTFS as same and make partitions from free space.

Comment: Turns out I cant shrink my D drive without formatting it. So I'll just use Wubi because I don't want to mess around with my drive. Thanks though :))

Answer (score 0):

I installed UBUNTU 13.04 on my laptop yesterday alongside Win 7 with Wubi.  During the installation, it asks to resize the partition.  I only have one HDD with a system partition (C: drive for windows) and another partition which I use for my backups and other data.

UBUNTU used some of THAT partition to install by making its own partition which is not accessible from windows file manager, but only visible on windows' disk manager.

Comment: Though it must be noted, that Wubi is deprecated now

Comment: Is there a problem with it, or has it just been "upgraded"

Comment: AFAIK there were some problems with it, and they decided it won't be supported in the future. It CAN be used, but it is not a future-proof solution.