# Installing Ubuntu on a separate drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, system-installation, ssd

I am wanting to use Ubuntu for daily use and my programming contract work (basically everything except for gaming). Right now I have Windows installed on a 64GB SSD and all of my Applications/Docs/Videos/Games/etc are installed on a separate HDD. In a month or so I am going to be getting a couple of new drives so i can get stop using two different drives for one OS (it just really bugs me having them separate for some reason).

I have already read [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323814/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-separate-hdd-to-my-windows-installation). However, I am asking a more fundamental question, *should I do this?*
Will I have a better experience doing it a different way?

So I was just considering re installing windows onto my HDD and then using the 64GB SSD for Ubuntu. Would that be an unwise decision on my part? Most Ubuntu installation tutorials I see either discuss installing as a partition or on a USB. So I am a little hesitant.

What do you all think? If it sounds okay, are there any tutorials out there for doing what I am talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from my own experience it is possible to install Ubuntu on a SSD drive, and it actually works quite well.

My Laptop had a 32GB SSD drive and a 500GB HDD that I wanted to split between Ubuntu and Windows.
I ended up installing Ubuntu on my 32GB SSD drive and splitting the HDD drive between the Windows installation and a media drive for Ubuntu.

Ubuntu boots really fast now, and working with the HDD drive is seamless, so I'm quite happy with the results. However, Windows' performance was cut down because I gave it a relativity small part from the HDD drive.

Should you do it?
It really depends on how you use Ubuntu and Windows relatively. If you just want Ubuntu as a lightweight OS that can be booted quickly then installing it on a 64GB drive, even without a media drive for heavy files, should be fine. That way you can give Windows the whole HDD drive like you suggested.

Please note that the performance improvement may be negligible, and installing an OS on a SSD drive does have its own risks. So you may want to think twice before deciding to play with an SSD installation.

If you decide that you do want to install Ubuntu on the SSD drive, then the  answer here  might guide you:
[Do I need Intel Smart Response when installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu)