# Is it safe to make SSD partitions bigger, than allowed by windows disk management?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I was trying to install ubuntu along with Windows 10. On my C: drive I have 275 GB of free space, from 100 GB of which I wanted to make a partition for ubuntu. Windows Disk Management only allows me to make 10 GB partition from my C: drive.

I know, that you could bypass that, by using third party software, but is there a possibility, that it will damage my operating system, or any of my files?
And also which app is best for partitioning SSD drives?

Comment: Linux does not have this restriction but I doubt windows has too... you have a problem with how windows disk management works so you need to ask windows users about windows tools.

Comment: Maybe your Windows partition is fragmented, so that there is no free continuous fragment bigger than 10 GB. Try to 'force' defragment the partition (when running Windows), and check again, if Windows accepts a larger new partition.

Comment: Turn off your pagefile/swapfile/hibernation in Windows, reboot, and you should be able to resize your C: partition.

Comment: @sudodus Never force anything. Just have to disable the page/swap/hibernation which uses fixed files that have to be moved out of the way.

Comment: @Rinzwind Pretty standard fix. Have to move page/swap/hibernation files out of the way in Windows.

Comment: @sudodus SSD's don't fragment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preparing a disk from Windows for installing Ubuntu (partitioning)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336749/preparing-a-disk-from-windows-for-installing-ubuntu-partitioning)

Answer (score 1):

Do not make a new partition with Windows. Just resize your C: (make it the 100 smaller) and leave unallocated space. Windows doesn't let you make EXT4 partitions if I remember right. You can make a partition for Ubuntu during install in the unallocated space. You don't need third party software.

Comment: OP is correctly using Windows Disk Management tools to resize their C: partition. page/swap/hibernation files are stopping their progress.

Comment: @ heynnema Yes, correct. You already told him to turn these of.