Where will Ubuntu be installed? Afraid to proceed
I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows (there is no option for this), but I'm afraid to proceed because I have no idea where Ubuntu is going to be installed.
I have made an partition for Ubuntu, but I can't choose to install it there. The installation program is somehow confusing. On the first photo on Manual partitioning I can't do anything, but I can see the partition where I want Ubuntu to be installed. On the second photo it's just showing the partitions where I have Windows, so I assume that it will install Ubuntu there. I haven't found any options to change this.
I want Ubuntu here:

Partitions:


You need unused space to install Ubuntu into. The screen shot shows you have formatted it as NTFS. It should not be formatted at all.

Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/336749/preparing-a-disk-from-windows-for-installing-ubuntu-partitioning

given the number of questions on here about losing everything Windoze when installing Ubuntu, backup all important stuff before proceeding with any installion if you are at all uncertain about what you are doing (as seems to be the case).
