# Ubuntu Installation Root partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have decided to install Ubuntu for office, programming and GFX along Windows 8.

I have made a USB - Bootstick and so on, created a 100GB partition for Ubuntu, so I wanted to install it on this partition, but he asks me for a root partition, but i still dont get what to do now.

Can u help me?

I am using Windwos 8 and have a Mainboard with UEFI.

Comment: Ok, can i use this partition to divide it in these two? How big should they be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update for Ubuntu 18.04 and above**

New installations of recent versions of Ubuntu does not use a separate swap partition any more. They use a swap file by default.

## Original Answer

**Some Basics**

Ubuntu needs at least two partitions to work well. One is called the root partition denoted by `/` and is formatted `ext4` and the other is called `Swap` with its own format. Windows does not understand these formats.

So you can't use Windows to create these partitions.

**What to do?**

The partition you created in Windows is not suitable for Ubuntu. **Delete the 100GB partition you have created and leave the space unallocated**.

When you install Ubuntu, it will find the unallocated space and create the partitions it needs automatically. The `Swap` will be a small partition (2-4 GB) used as virtual RAM and the rest of 100GB will be `/`.

See [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

and [Ubuntu installation on Windows7 with D partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition) for more details.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is what I wanted to know, I will try it and come back later!

Comment: Ok here I am, it worked until the final installation then the installation programm crashed because GRUB couldnt been installated. The swap partition hasnt been automatically. He asked me but i had no other partition so I went forward without a swap partition....

Comment: Did you choose manual partition (something else)? Search for **GRUB Repair" to fix the GRUB problem.