# I made a partition on my nvme disk for installing ubuntu and make a dual boot system with Windows and ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, nvme

But my partition doesnt appear on ubuntu installation. It shows the whole disk as one and does not have my partition, What should i do ?

Comment: i need you help :)

Comment: More details needed. Where exactly does the partition not appear? What is shown and what do you expect to be shown?

Comment: Also see [Ubuntu Installation Root partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368989/ubuntu-installation-root-partition/369156#369156). Please note Ubuntu does not need a separate `swap` partition any more. Recent versions of Ubuntu uses a swap file by default.

Comment: In the proccess of the installation, when i have to select the disk which i will install the os, i select the "Something else" option and there it appears to have the whole 1tb disk and it was not seperate to partitions. I made the partition because i want to use that disk also on windows

Comment: In some cases Windows partitions are not recognized by Ubuntu. For example, if Windows uses [dynamic disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks#basic-and-dynamic-disks). In these situation the Ubuntu installer may see the whole physical SSD/HDD as unused. Something Else may ask you to create a new partition table. If you do that, you will lose your Windows partitions and all the all the data along with the Windows installation.