# Is it OK to format these partitions in SCSI2?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm installing Ubuntu as a dual boot alongside Windows. I finally got a partition on my HDD (which is different than my SSD on which Windows is installed). While installing Ubuntu, I get to a message about how it will format certain partitions, which is normal, but it has "Partition #3 of SCSI2, Partition #4 of SCSI2, and Partition #5 of SCSI2" set to be formatted. Is that right? I only want it to use the 20GB partition on my F: drive, and nothing else.

[image]

Comment: See this answer for some ideas: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition/204699#204699

Comment: I did it, and it didnt destroy any of my data!

Comment: Please answer your own question with the details, so it may help others. How did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your F: drive **is itself a partition** on some disk. You cannot install Ubuntu on your F: drive--but you may install it **on the same disk** as your F: drive.

The message displayed by the installer means that:

- It is using a disk named `/dev/sdb`, most likely your HDD.
- On that disk it has created 3 partitions:

  - One [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) (`/dev/sdb3`)
  - One **ext4** partition (`/dev/sdb4`) for use by Ubuntu as the root filesystem
  - One swap partition (`/dev/sdb5`)

This is normal for a new installation on a computer which uses UEFI and a disk which uses a GPT partition table.

It is likely that your HDD already had a [Microsoft Reserved Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) and a [Microsoft basic data partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition) (your F: drive), which in Linux would be `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`.

As user @waltinator rightly [says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852762/how-to-dual-boot-windows-after-installing-ubuntu),

> Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test), [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS), [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI) is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: Oh cmon, it ridiculous to link 5 wikipedia pages and say "anyone who doesnt read this is dumb!" It's shouldnt be this hard. Anyway, I hit continue and it was fine.