# Disk Space not detected

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management

I was using Windows7 system. To install Ubuntu I created partition of 100GB. Downloaded Ubuntu installer for windows and installed Ubuntu. The system is working perfectly fine but it is showing disk space of 20 GB only. Where as the drive where Ubuntu is installed is 100 GB

Can any one tell me how can start using remaining 80 GB ?

I have tried disks application but could not understand how it is installed/shown

Answer (score 2):

You have done the WUBI installation. Wubi has some [limitation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) Wubi installs Ubuntu on a large virtual partition that is a single big file called the root.disk. In your case, this file seems to be 20GB and is located in the 100GB partition you created.

**What to do?**

Ubuntu has its own partition format `ext4` and can't use the format used by Windows. To install Ubuntu in its own partition, you have to create a live DVD/USB and boot directly from the DVD/USB.

Before you boot from Ubuntu DVD/USB, you should delete the 100GB partition while you are in Windows. This will create 100GB free space that Ubuntu will recognize and create its own set of partitions in.

See the following links at Ubuntu.com for detailed instructions:

[How to make Live DVD.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

[How to make Live USB.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

[Steps to install Ubuntu.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

Also see:

[Ubuntu installation on Windows7 with D partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition/204699#204699)

[I have formatted a partition for Ubuntu. How do I install it on that partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204653/i-have-formatted-a-55gb-partition-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-how-do-i-install-it-on)

[Dual Boot Installation with Win7 - Install Ubuntu in New Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189788/dual-boot-installation-with-win7-install-ubuntu-in-new-partition)

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Hope this helps.